# How to disable chrome extensions JS when debugging in devtools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

When I add mouse event breakpoint, devtools always jump into extension's JS.

Is there any way to point to my mouse event code directly?

Comment: I think a clarification could help here. What do you mean by "to point to my mouse event code directly"?

Comment: @ronme suppose I'm debugging some page's js,listening all the mousedown event, devtools will show the mousedown handler registered in the extension's js code. Is there any way to show the mousedown handler in the page's js directly?

Comment: in the debugger, you should be able to choose which js file you're looking at. Once you choose the page's js file, you should be able to set a breakpoint there. Does that not work?

Answer (score 20):

The only way to *disable* the script (e.g. to avoid side-effects) is by disabling the extension (for instance, by using incognito mode if the extension is not enabled in incognito mode).

If you don't mind the scripts to run, but want to ignore extension code, then you can use the script [blackboxing feature of Chrome's devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/step-code#tip-name-functions-to-improve-call-stack-readability).

If you never develop extensions and aren't interested in stepping through it, then open the settings menu of the devtools, click on Blackboxing and then the "Blackbox content scripts" checkbox:

[image]

If you only want to selectively ignore files, then you can also right-click on the source of the file that you want to ignore, and click on the "Blackbox Script" contextmenu option. To remove the pattern, go to the "Blackboxing" settings panel as shown before.

Comment: Just to note: It appears that sometimes this blackboxing of extensions' code stops working for a given domain/dev-tools instance. In that case, find the dev-tools task in Task Manager, kill it, close the tab, then reopen the website in a new tab. That's the only way I've found to restore the blackboxing behavior when it breaks (once in a blue moon).

Comment: The _Blackboxing_ tab is now _Ignore List_ and the _Blackbox content scripts_ option is now _Add content scripts to ignore list_

Comment: Blackbox script is now ignore list.  I checked the checkbox add content script to ignore list and it didn't work for me.  I had to explicitly add this to the ignore list: ^chrome-extension://

Answer (score 18):

I think the simplest way is to open an *incognito window* (<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-N</kbd>) (or <kbd>Cmd-Shift-N</kbd> for mac) and debug in there, because then there will be no extensions loaded (by default).

I know what you mean by this question: when debugging, and doing something simple like pausing execution, you always find it breaks into one of the extension's codes instead of the current webpage's code.

Answer (score 6):

[image: explicity ignore list]

open developer tools, then go to settings and then click on ignore list, and check the checkbox for add content script to ignore list, then add this to the ignore list: **^chrome-extension://**

Answer (score 1):

I like to use **Profiles** for that.

While changing into **incognito mode** might help you to disable most of the extensions, some of them might be allowed and still run. For example I have DarkReader and Ublock enabled in incognito mode.

My favorite workaround is to use a "Guest" profile or to create a profile that you can use for debugging. I think it is easier than creating a Framework Ignore List inside of devtools.

How to create a profile: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824

Example: [My debugging profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua8HB.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google Chrome (or any Chromium-based browsers), simply run a new browser instance with a fresh user's data directory.

On Linux:

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d)
```

This way, all extensions will be disabled without having to manually switch off/on them.

Answer (score -1):

First off you should probably review the tutorial on how to debug chrome extensions here:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html

When in doubt, you can always use the `debugger` keyword directly in the JavaScript code where you want to launch the debugger from, like so:

```
element.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    debugger;
    // some JS handler code...
});
```

Depending on if your JS is in a popup, background page, or in a content script, you will need make sure you launch the dev tools from the right place.

For a popup, you need to right click on the extension icon and "Inspect Popup" and then from the JavaScript console you would need to run `location.reload(true)`

For a background page, you need to go to the extensions settings page, `chrome://settings/extensions`, turn on developer mode, expand the extension in question and click the background page link.

The content script should be visible directly from the page it is loaded onto.

Comment: He's not asking how to debug extensions. He's asking how to *prevent* the debugger from going into extensions when he's debugging normal webapps.