# chrome-extension:// keeps grabbing Chrome Dev Tools focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Very frequently while trying to use the Chrome Dev Tools console to debug a web app the context keeps switching to `chrome-extension://` and so my commands are getting addressed to the wrong frame. I manually have to switch it back to `top`.

What causes the focus to change? And is there a way for me to lock the console to `top`?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look too good.. You may have to just disable the extension :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862330/how-to-disable-chrome-extensions-js-when-debugging-in-devtools

Comment: It's obviously a Chrome bug. This one, I guess: https://crbug.com/626415

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm -- that does looks to be the one! Can you leave it as an answer so I can accept it?